# Format (line length) of javadoc (or other) comments

Tags: comments

Is there a convention saying how long a line of comment should be?

Different line lengths will not work for any monitor size, or even font size, and other collaborators reading the code will have to scroll back and forth horizontally to read the entire line. I am wondering how this type of stuff is solved in the real world where people collaborate with other coders. Or is there some kind of auto formatter where people can change this kind of stuff on-the-fly to their own taste maybe?

For example:

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
 * adipisicing elit. Libero pariatur maxime 
 * praesentium. Similique qui, non aliquam 
 * nulla libero tenetur voluptatibus delectus, 
 * ex ab, aspernatur nam animi ipsa. Beatae 
 **/
```

versus:

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam iste magni optio 
 * impedit rem labore minima cumque quaerat corrupti suscipit dicta, possimus commodi 
 * laudantium ipsam, tenetur. Omnis qui, veritatis eligendi dignissimos rem quos 
 * voluptatum quaerat neque at excepturi quod fugit veniam sapiente sunt blanditiis, 
 * autem illum alias delectus illo, nostrum, dolore aspernatur culpa. Omnis ea deserunt, 
 * vero odio praesentium repellendus enim recusandae at temporibus officia, obcaecati 
 **/
```

(I apologise if this is the wrong stackexchange site to ask this, I honestly didn't know where to put it)

Comment: if you use phpstorm you can add your own copyright box or comment box

Comment: if you want to know how that will be done i'll post an answer how to do it with phpstorm

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for a universal answer, if there is one. It's more of a convention-type question, rather than how I solve it only for myself. If it applies even.

Comment: yeah its sad but its programm-specific

Comment: Well that's okay, if that's what it is, then that's how it is. I just wanted to know. Maybe in the future someone starts a good convention for comments as well!

Comment: yeah that's what all dev's want. one unique "code-comment-formating"